# How to inherit phpdoc from another method (not the one we are overwriting)

Tags: php, phpdoc

I was wandering if there is a method to copy (inherit) exact same phpdoc on different methods in the same and/or different classes.

I know about [inline {@inheritdoc}](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.inlineinheritdoc.pkg.html), which only provide inheritance from a parent to its child class (as one should expect :).

But look at the following, there i have to copy the very same description in 3 different places, 2 methods in the same class and one in a separate class (not inherited but initiated). 
I was wondering if there is a method that might does the trick, without copy pasting.

```
class Example
{
    /**
     * here i want to have exactly the same phpdoc,
     * like what i created for getMeSomethingFromTheShelf() in the same class
     */
    public function getMeSomething($id, $option = [])
    {
        return $this->getMeSomethingFromTheShelf($id, $option);
    }

    /**
     * Some description
     * and some more detail about how the $option value will be used
     *
     * @param int $id
     * @param array $option and here some we have some sample
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMeSomethingFromTheShelf($id, $option = [])
    {
    return 'here you go :)';
    }
}

class AnotherClass
{
    /**
     * here also i want to have exactly the same phpdoc,
     * like what i created for Example::getMeSomethingFromTheShelf() in the Example class
     */
    public function fetchSomething($id, $option = [])
    {
        return (new Example)->getMeSomething($id, $option = []);
    }
}
```

Thanks for any suggestion, in advance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`{@inheritdoc}` is a built-in, without support for specifying the inheritance source.  Please make use of the `@see` tag.

It is unlikely that two methods should be described the same way.  If it is a proxy, or simply passes data through, the description should note this behavior, and the `@see` tag should direct the user to the interfaced method.

I routinely use the `@see` and `@link` tags to link to SAPI documentation, or to resolve proxies.  That said, I always try to include some sort of description as well, and always document parameters and returns, even if they are identical (helps when looking at the code).

Be careful of getting too reliant on PHPDoc's shortcuts.

Comment: The @see tag cannot refer to a namespace element.

Comment: @james - The documentations does say that (verbatim, actually). However, it is unclear what that means exactly, as the documentation also provides examples of referencing namespaced classes/methods.  Do you have any insight as to what that caveat means, exactly? https://docs.phpdoc.org/3.0/guide/references/phpdoc/inline-tags/see.html

Comment: yeah, standards, and HTTP status codes, have some solid definition but there's still some subjectivity as people have varying scenarios. I'm not 100% sure to be honest.

Comment: @James OH, I understand now:  `@see` can reference a URI, and a PHP-Namespace (class/method/function/etc), but not an XML-Namespace (which are typically in a URI format).  Is that what it is referring to?